# Xcode 11 how to delete the MAC version of a multi device target IOS app (iPhone, iPad, Mac)

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to completely delete my IOS app because of a core data problem. The app should start with as it never had been tested on the MAC. On the simulator and on the physical iPhone and iPad I can delete the app, but I can't figure out where the MAC version is physically stored on the MAC? I already did a clean build folder and deleted the derived data folder (I found the core data itself under Data/Library/Application Support) but not where I can delete the entire app.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the entire app"? What happens if you select the app from the Products menu in Xcode, right-click, and choose Show in Finder? Doing that should take you to the app in the Finder so you can remove it. Deleting the derived data folder should delete the app itself.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking too. But there is still something left on the MAC because I am getting some error messages regarding the core data libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report: "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model". If I delete the same app on the iPhone and rebuild it the app runs without an error.